# convert csv items in a list box to a table in mysql database

Tags: c#, winforms

I am very new to this game and have not got a lot of experience coding, so forgive if this is an odd question.
I have a windows form app in C# that has a child form which reads qr codes and converts the output from a web cam to items in a list box. There are 3 list boxes  items from each scan are added to each list box when a button is pushed. The first scan button produces items in list box 1 the second button produces items in list box 2 etc. Because I am trying to fit a lot of information into each list box my first list box produces items separated by commas i.e name,age,sex,id number, the second list box single items (drug) and the 3rd list box single items (quantity).
What i am looking to do is populate a table in MS sql database with each individual item in its own column i.e column1: Name, column 2: age, column 3: sex etc.
Is there a way of converting the listbox1 items from CSV to single words and to add all 3 list box items to a single table?

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Start at the beginning - look at `string.Split(',');` and then look at making database connections, then creating tables and then insert statements.  Everything you need is easily available.  You won't get an answer to such a broad request on here.  This site is more for *"Here's my code.  I expect it to do this but it does that."*, not *"Make my app for me"*

Comment: It's not a case of write my code for me more that fact that when I said "new to this game" what I meant was strings are something until now I used to tie things up with.

Comment: I was looking more for " you will need to write the listbox items to a string then use ........ to split the string and then each item can be stripped to the database using a warpdrive flange spinner". That way I have something I can go away and research each part and hopefully put them together somehow and wahla.

Answer (score 0):

If it's pseudo-code you want...

Note, there is little DB interaction guidance here...that is way too large a topic.

```
foreach (var item in listBox.Items)
{
    var sa = item.ToString().Split(',');
    if (sa.Length == 4)  //whatever it ought to be, optional sanity check
    {
        using (myNewSqlConnection)
        using (myNewSqlCommand)
        {
            //Data type is important here, so pay attention to that
            myNewSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@par1", System.Data.DbType.String).Value = sa[0];  //@par1 would be in the SQL for parameterized query

           //Once you've added all of the values, execute the query.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Don Cheers I shall put it all together and see what happens. I have some code that connects to a DB in another form which should give me enough to bastardise something. Cheers All